# Disable explicit commit in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm currently working on improving the indexing speed of a application where I do not have full control of the code that performs the indexing. I have found out that the indexing code makes a commit after each document, something that I would like to avoid for performance reasons.

**Question:**

> Is it possible in Solr to disable all commits made explicitly from a
>   client and instead only rely on auto commits configured in the Solr config?

Comment: Dont think that is possible. You need to the control of the indexing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart question!

I've seen the same in a lot of applications, that's the first mistake everybody makes. It's not possible in Solr out of the box but something you can achieve writing your own [`UpdateRequestProcessor`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) I think.

As of now this is not possible to do in configuration but you could probably override the [`processCommit`](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/UpdateRequestProcessor.html#processCommit%28org.apache.solr.update.CommitUpdateCommand%29) method with an empty method, or just a log line. That should work fine unless the autocommit uses the same workflow, which shouldn't be the case but I would check. Anyway you can easily test this.

Once you've written your own component you have to make it available to solr as a jar and configure it in the update request processor chain (`solrconfig.xml`):

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain>
    <processor class="solr.NoCommitUpdateRequestProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Don't forget the last two lines which are the default request processors, otherwise all the update requests will do nothing!

Comment: I can accept this solution but I think its a bit ugly :) But then again that's not your fault.

Is it ok if we ad a disclaimer in your answer telling people not to do this if they read this question? ;)

Basically just add "As of yet this is not possible, but you could ..." at the top of your question.

Comment: Yep,
Maybe we should open a ticket in Jira for this?

I'll edit your answer and accept it. :)

Comment: I wouldn't say that's something you should not do. It's the only way to achieve what you want, but you have to write some code for it. Update request processors are a nice way to hook into the solr update workflow. Creating an issue and contributing this back to the project as well would be great.

Comment: The best way would be to make it really clear (in Solr) that the commit is something you shouldn't call per document (using a different endpoint for instance), and enable auto-commit by default, like elasticsearch does ;)

Comment: Yep, I agree. I edited and added "As of now this is not possible to do in configuration but". Hope that's ok :)

Answer (score 1):

As of Solr 5.3 (if not earlier) you can add the following to solrconfig.xml:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="ignore-commit-from-client" default="true">
  <processor class="solr.IgnoreCommitOptimizeUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <int name="statusCode">200</int>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

See: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html#ShardsandIndexingDatainSolrCloud-IgnoringCommitsfromClientApplicationsinSolrCloud